# Android Change Theme Inside App

Tags: android, android-theme

How to change theme inside android app?I have activity with settings where I can select Light or Dark theme.

Settings Activity
[image]
**Can I use something like this:**

```
public class OTGEnabler extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otgenabler);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String theme = sharedPrefs.getString("Choose Theme",null);
        if(theme != null && theme.equals("Light"))
        {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        }
        else
        {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_AppBarOverlay);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is error log:

> 02-04 07:16:40.023 23924-23924/com.example.pavle.usbotgenabler
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.pavle.usbotgenabler, PID: 23924
>                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.pavle.usbotgenabler/com.example.pavle.usbotgenabler.otg_enaber.OTGEnabler}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action
>   bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has
>   an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request
>   Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in
>   your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:203)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:133)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.pavle.usbotgenabler.otg_enaber.OTGEnabler.onCreate(OTGEnabler.java:80)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: I tried to run app again and it starts but when I select light or dark from list preference menu nothing happens !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `setTheme(..)` inside `onCreate`  **before** calling `setContentView(...)`and `super.oncreate()`  and it should work, Not after them!

---

<sub>Extra help</sub>

Add an edit text in your view

Theme One

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Theme Two

```
<style name="AppThemeTwo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

If you add these two you will notice difference in your `EditText` like  cursor color  cursor pointer color  etc..

Answer (score 0):

In **androidManifest.xml** file change theme of settings activity to new theme which you want for settings activity.

this new theme must be defined in **values->style.xml**

If not present add to settings activity in androidManifest.xml file following xml tag
**android:theme**

Comment: I added theme but when I select settings from navigation drawer I get error application has stopped working !!! <activity android:name=".settings.Settings"
                  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

Comment: Why do you want log cat?